# How to insert array into database? Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel

this might be a different question from the questions that has been asked here already about inserting arrays into the database, but mine is quite different.

Here's the code:

```
public function something(Request $request)
{
  $id = $request ->id;
  $name = $request->name;
  $money = $request ->money;

  $data = array(
    'name' => $name, 
    'money' => $money,
  );

  $z = User::where('id',$id)
    ->select('name','money')
    ->first();

  $data2 = array(
    'name' => $z->name,
    'money' => $z->money,
  );

  $diff = array_diff($data,$data2);
  $diff_name = array_keys($diff);
  $diff_values = array_values($diff);
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($diff_name); $i++) {
    $z->$diff_name[$i] = $diff_values[$i];
    $z->save();
  }
  return 'Success';
}
```

Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','money'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}


$data:
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Somewhere" ["money"]=> string(7) "5123.00"}

 $data2:
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Anywhere" ["money"]=> string(7) "5000.00"}
```

So I'm using **array_diff** to determine if the values that has been entered by the user is equal from the original value from the database, if theres a difference in value then get the column name(**$diff_name**) and then insert the new value(**$diff_value**).
I did it this way since I will be needing the values of $diff_name for history log purposes.
However I'm getting this error **`Array to string conversion`**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include relevant code of your User model class, it may help us assist you better. There might be an easy way to ensure the value gets cast to a JSON string for insertion and parsed as array when accessing it. [Check here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Comment: @segFault added, hope it will help

Comment: What does your `$data` array look like? Can you `var_dump()` it and add to your question as well? I am thinking that those values are actually arrays and not strings.

Comment: @segFault edited.

Comment: hmm, not what I was expecting. So where is the error occurring exactly? Do you have the line where it complains? it might be nested in a stack trace, that might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is are several built in Eloquent methods that you could implement.

```php
    public function something(Request $request)
    {
      $z = User::where('id',$request->id)
        ->select('name','money')
        ->first(); // You could also use '->firstOrFail()' if you want to stop execution if a model was not retrieved. 

      $z->fill([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'money' => $request->money,
      ]);


      $diff = array_keys($z->getDirty());

      $z->save()'

      return 'Success';
    }
```

> **$model->firstOrFail()**
>
> Can be used to stop execution to prevent an error from trying to
>   manipulate a model which was not retrieved from the database.

---

> **$model->fill()**
>
> This can be used to pass an array of values which you would like to
>   update.

---

> **$request->only(['name','money])**
>
> Instead of passing an array to `$model->fill()` you could have also
>   used this.

---

> **$model->getDirty()**
>
> After changing a models attributes (and before saving it) you can use
>   this to get an associative array of the attributes and corresponding
>   values which have changed.